# Add all primary key constraints in non clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing, ddl, non-clustered-index

I have created a table with the following columns. All columns are unique key (column) there is no primary key in my table.

Table `Product`:

```
Bat_Key,
product_no,
value,
pgm_name,
status,
industry,
created_by,
created_date
```

I have altered my table to add constraints

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PRODUCT_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Bat_Key] ASC, [product_no] ASC,
                                  [value] ASC, [pgm_name] ASC, )
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And if I created indexes as below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PRODUCT_BKEY_PNO_IDX] 
ON [dbo].[PRODUCT] ([Bat_Key] ASC, [product_no] ASC, [value], [pgm_name])
INCLUDE ([status], [industry]) 
         WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Whether this design is good for the following select queries :

```
select * 
from Product 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=? 
order by product_no, pgm_name;

select * 
from Product 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=? and pgm_name = ? and value = ?

select * 
from Product 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=?

delete from Product 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=?
```

or should I create different indexes based on my `where` clauses?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, primary key automatically creates a clustered index. It might be unnecessary to create a non clustered index on the same fields.

Comment: A primary key constraint is always backed by a unique index, whether clustered or not. The `PRODUCT_BKEY_PNO_IDX` index would be redundant. (It cannot be used in your queries because it's not covering; the `created_*` fields would still need to be looked up in any `SELECT *`.) You typically want a clustered index anyway, even if it's only on an `IDENTITY` field you will not otherwise use. Such a field can also serve as a much more practical surrogate key for use within the database than something as broad as four fields including text.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This is a product specific question.)

Comment: @jarlh - am using Azure SQL database

Comment: There are no performance absolutes. Want to know? You test your queries and examine the execution plans. And NOTHING is free. There is a cost to maintaining additional indexes. Focusing on just a few SELECT statements can give you misleading direction. More importantly - you should carefully consider whether a heap is appropriate for this table and its usage.

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index is very different from a non-clustered index. Effectively, types both indexes contain the data sorted according to the columns you specify. However,

- The clustered index also contains the rest of the data in the table (except for a few things like nvarchar(max)). You can consider this to be how it's saved in the database
- Non-clustered indexes only contain the columns you have included in the index

If you don't have a clustered index, you have a 'heap'. Instead of a PK, they have a row identifiers built in.

In your case, as your primary key is **non-clustered**, it makes *no sense to make another index with the same fields*. To read the data, it must get the row identifier(s) from your PK, then go and read the data from the heap.

If, on the other hand, your primary key is **clustered** (which is the default), having a non-clustered index on the fields can be useful in some circumstances. But note that every non-clustered index you add can also slow down updates, inserts and deletes (as the indexes must be maintained as well).

In your example - say you had a field there which was a varchar(8000) on the row which contains a lot of information. To even read one row from the clustered index, it must read (say) 100 bytes from the other fields, and up to 8000 bytes from that new field. In other words, it multiplies the amount you need to read by 80x.

I have a tendency to have see tables having two types of data

- Data you aggregate
- Data you only care about on a row-by-row level

For example, in a transaction table, you may have transaction_id, transaction_date, transaction_amount, transaction_description, transaction_entered_by_user_id.

- In most cases, whenever you're getting totals etc, you'll frequently need transaction amounts, date when looking at totals (e.g., what was the total of transactions this week?)
- On the other hand, the description and user_id are only used when you refer to specific rows (e.g., who did this specific transaction?)
- In these cases, I often put a non-clustered index on the fields used in aggregation, even if they overlap with the clustered index. It just reduces the amounts of reads required.

A really good video on this is by Brent Ozar called [How to think like the SQL Server Engine](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/01/how-to-think-like-the-engine-2019-edition/) - I strongly recomment it as it helped me a lot in understanding how indexes are used.

---

Regarding your specific examples - there are two things to look for in indexes:

1. The ability to 'seek' to a specific point in the data set (based on the sort of the index).
2. Capability to reduce amount to be read.

In terms of allowing seeks, you need to sort the index in the most appropriate way. When doing it for filtering (e.g., WHERE clauses, JOINs, one rule of thumb is to first look for 'exact' matches. For these, it doesn't matter what order they are in, as long as they have all the ones up to that point.

In your case, you have

```
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=? 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=? and pgm_name = ? and value = ?
```

This suggests your first two fields should be Bat_Key and product_no (in either order). Then you can also have pgm_name and value (also in either order).

You also have

```
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=? 
order by product_no, pgm_name;
```

which suggests to me that the third field should be pgm_name (as an index on Bat_Key, product_no and pgm_name would provide what you need there).

However - and this is a big however - you have lots of *s in there e.g.,

```
select * 
from Product 
where Bat_Key = ? and product_no=?
```

Because you are selecting *, any index that is not the clustered index needs to also go back to the actual rows to get the rest of what's included in the *.

As these want all the fields from the table (not just the ones in the index) it will need to go back to the heap (in your case). If you had a clustered index on the fields above, as well as a non-clustered index, it would have to read from the clustered index anyway because information is in there that is needed for your query.

Once again - the video above - explains this much better than I do.

Therefore, in your case, I suggest the following Primary Key

```
ADD CONSTRAINT [PRODUCT_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Bat_Key] ASC, [product_no] ASC,
                                  [pgm_name] ASC, [value] ASC)
```

Differences

- It is clustered rather than non-clustered
- The order of the 3rd and 4th fields are rearranged to help with the order by pgm_name
- No real need for a second non-clustered index as there is not much other stuff to be read.